# How much data can 1GB MySQL handle

Tags: mysql, sqlite

I am going to launch a startup that will have many users, and I want to store a huge amount of data in the database. Some friend out there suggested me some HostingProviderA. (name not enclosed)

I was about to going on to sign for the Hosting Package by HostingProviderA
but they have clearly listed in their package details that each MySQL can contain 1GB for each of the database we contain.

Question are here as follows, struck in my mind and need to be cleared.

1. Just wanted to know how much data can I store in 1GB data.
2. If I want to host my own server then how much data can be stored with Ubuntu 32 bit 20GB storage VPS plan.
3. What is difference between MySQL and SQLite?

Comment: 1GB data can represent 1GB, I guess... (unless compressed).

Comment: What is difference between MySQL and SQLite? Google can tell better. yes, its true. There are lots of details and technical comparison out there.

Comment: I don't know why my question is downvoted? I have asked Genuine Problem, I's facing. Someone please upvote this Question, So I can ask any further Question.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

1. Depends on how you organize your database and how many tables/fields you have... I run a forum that has about 50 tables and 1.5 million records and it's 460MB.
2. The VPS would be important if you are going to be doing some custom stuff (large scripts, lots of MySQL processing etc..) You have much more control over the VPS.  In shared hosting, if another site has a problem, you have a much better chance your site will be slow/unresponsive.
3. SQLlite is a bare bones base SQL server, typically packaged for local applications/phones etc... MySQL is an enterprise relational DB.

Comment: You saved my life. Basically, these are the things, I want to know.

Answer (score 1):

for 1. It depends on your database structure. Do you have fixed length fields, many relations, indexes, etc. Calculate with additional 10-20% of non-data space. so you can store about 800MB of pure data.

depending on your database structure you might use that space in an optimal way.

for 2. if you like to have many users and a huge amount of data - don't use a VPS-plan.

for 3. [maybe this can help you](http://blog.sobbayi.com/sqlite-vs-mysql-how-to-decide-which-to-use/)